# lo + adjective/adverb + que + clause in Spanish VS the adjective (superlative) + (that) + clause in English

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, linguistics, spanish

Recently I learned a Spanish grammar "lo+adjective/adverb+que+clause" to translate"how ..." (indicative) of English.
But I found the structure unusual because "lo+adjective" itself serves as a noun, which is another grammar in Spanish, but the adjective/adverb in the subordinate clause serve as a predicate/adverbial.
And that reminds us of one unusual structure in English:

> The closest (that) I ever came to Deng was a few feet away at a reception at the National Gallery in Washington in January 1979. (Deng Xiaoping and the Transformation of China)

> That's about the fastest that current rocket engines can propel a spacecraft, and it's far shorter than the 253 days Curiosity took to get to Mars in 2012. (CNN: SHARE THIS)

Another case is：
I run the fastest that I can
corro lo más rápido que puedo
(However, this English sentence may not be correct because I met it in a similar topic on Stack Exchange.)

Anyway, in this structure "the closest ... (that) ...", [the closest] serves as a noun in the main clause, but serves as an adverbial in the subordinate clause.

So my question is, do the two similar structures have something to do with each other?

Comment: Yes. They are both examples of recursion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion. The apparently substantivised adjective is anaphoric or must be defined.

Comment: I am sorry I may not be able to agree with that. Not long after I posted this question, I found that, according to The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston & Pullum, the superlative adjective/adverb can serve as an antecedent in a relative clause.

Comment: *the superlative adjective/adverb can serve as an antecedent in a relative clause.* this does not preclude recursion. In *The closest (that) I ever came to Deng*,  "that I ever came to Deng" is a defining relative clause with the referent "the closest". "The closest" must have a referent (or you must assume ellipsis.) In this case, "the closest" refers to "the closest **distance**" -- In the case of "the fastest", fastest has the referent speed. The referent may be exophoric if both parties are likely to know it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. But I suggest not adding a head in a relative clause introduced by AdvP/AdjP, because the head can't syntactically serve as an adj/adv in the relative clause. But there is one case that you can add a head---fused head NP. This is the best that I have ever seen. In this sentence, the best ( ) is a fused-head NP, and the relative clause syntactically needs a noun.

Comment: **that I have ever seen.** (relative clause) cannot take a noun. You may mean "*the best* requires a noun".

Comment: Can you re-phrase that with no reference toSpanish?